# jQuery insert after li element with attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have list:

```
<ul class="customList">
    <li data-featured="1">First item</li>
    <li data-featured="0">Another item</li>
    <li data-featured="0">Last item..</li>
</ul>
```

How can I insert my custom `<li>` after `featured="1"`? If all featured 0, then insert as first `li`.. Thanks in advance.

```
var self = this;
self.scope.find('.customList').prepend(myCustomItem); //this code inserts in begin, not after featured items..
$(myCustomItem).insertAfter('[data-featured="1"]'); //I've tried to build something.. but this fails
```

Sorry for my bad English

EDIT

`myCustomItem.insertAfter('[data-featured="1"]');` looks like is working, but when there is any data-featured=1, then nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Comment: you question is bit unclear. Please elaborate a bit more

Comment: Please if any of the below answers helped you, don't forget to approve, by clicking the **Check Mark** at the left side of the answer. Good Luck !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use the jQuery [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) [attribute=value]: to check if `li` with `data-featured="1"` is exist or not. If exist then use the jQuery method [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) to insert the new li after it and if not then insert new li at the first position using [`.insertBefore().`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

```js
if($('.customList li[data-featured="1"]').length>0)
{
      $("<li data-featured='99'>NEW ITEM</li>").insertAfter('.customList li[data-featured="1"]');
}
else
{
      $("<li data-featured='99'>NEW ITEM</li>").insertBefore('.customList li:first');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="customList">
    <li data-featured="0">First item</li>
    <li data-featured="0">Another item</li>
    <li data-featured="0">Last item..</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you so much

Comment: Glad it helps you. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Use the *jQuery* [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) `[attribute=value]`:

```js
$(" <li data-featured='222'>NEW ITEM</li>").insertAfter('.customList li[data-featured="1"]');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="customList">
    <li data-featured="1">First item</li>
    <li data-featured="0">Another item</li>
    <li data-featured="0">Last item..</li>
</ul>
```

Or if you want to insert it after the first `li` tag the, use this:

```js
$(" <li data-featured='222'>NEW ITEM</li>").insertAfter('.customList li:first');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="customList">
    <li data-featured="1">First item</li>
    <li data-featured="0">Another item</li>
    <li data-featured="0">Last item..</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This answer works.. why is it downvoted

Comment: @ProEvilz as You I don't unedrstand why !

Comment: Works if there are data-featured=1, but If all li elements have data-featured=0, then nothing happens

Comment: You should be **EXTREMELY** straight forward given the example above with a simple if statement. I'm going to remove my answers and not bother helping as you're toxic. At this point it is being lazy.

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi do you thing the html structure is correct. You are nested li within li by appending!!! why are you using `append()` when question is about insert after something?

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo Edition Done !

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would say **don't use** `append()` when the question is about insert after an `li`. Check below snippet, first check the condition for `data-featured=1` available or not and then `prepend()` or `insertAfter()` based on that.

```js
var flag = false;
$('.customList li').each(function() {
  if ($(this).data('featured') == '1') {
    flag = true;
  }
});
if (flag) {  
  $("<li data-featured='222'>NEW ITEM</li>").insertAfter('.customList li[data-featured="1"]');
} else {
  $('.customList').prepend(" <li data-featured='222'>NEW ITEM</li>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="customList">
  <li data-featured="1">First item</li>
  <li data-featured="0">Another item</li>
  <li data-featured="0">Last item..</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newStatus.insertAfter('[data-featured="1"]');
```

Works fine but just have to check for the case when the item added is the first item or not. That can be easily done by if condition. 
something like this:

```
if($('li[data-featured="1"]') != null)
```

here is the example:  [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/shyam004/0uh4Lu8z/)

Comment: Almost here, but when I create `else { $('.customList').append(myCustomItem); }` Then else is not working, why?

Comment: `myCustomItem` won't work directly, you need to write it like `$('ul').append("<li data-featured='222'>myCustomItem</li>");`

Comment: if myCustomItem is array the you need to take a loop. iterate the array and then add it back to <ul> tag

Comment: Nah, if I write `if($('li[data-featured="1"]') != null){alert('first');}else{alert('second');} And always I got alert first. Why?`

Comment: if($('li[data-featured="1"]').val() != null) .... you need to take `.val()` like shown here.